# If $F$ is a radical extension of $E$ and $E$ is a radical extension of $K$...

Tags: abstract-algebra

Can someone walk me through the proof for the statement:

If $F$ is a radical extension field of
$E$ and $E$ is a radical extension field of $K$, then $F$ is a
radical extension of $K$.

Comment: This is pretty immediate if you define a radical extension as a tower of extensions $F_0 \subset \cdots \subset F_n$ such that there exist $\alpha_i,k_i$ so that $F_i(\alpha_i)=F_{i+1}$ and $\alpha_i^{k_i} \in F_i$.